# 404 error for deploying flask app in vercel

Tags: flask, vercel

I was trying to deploy my ai chatbot app through vercel but it keeps giving 404 not found error.

This is my GitHub link to the project: https://github.com/Nihael-Keel/Yashika

Please help debug my folder

I tried changing the output directory to . But that didn’t work